# RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED

Tags: postgresql

I want to try avg() aggregation within a time window 
sql code

```
select
user_id,timestamp
avg(y) over(range between '5 second' preceding and '5 second' following),
from A
```

but the system report error

```
RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED
```

Is there any method to implement, say, a 10 second window for avg() window function?

frame of window function is as wide as range from n seconds preceding the timestamp of current row and m seconds following the timestamp of current row

Comment: What is a "10 second window"? Where does the time come from?

Comment: @zerkms frame of window function is as wide as range from n seconds preceding the timestamp of current row and m seconds following the timestamp of current row  see updated question  thanks:)

Comment: I know what frame of a window function is. I cannot understand where you get time from. Let's say you have a row. Where do you get time from? "the timestamp of current row " --- what's this?

Comment: the timestamp column in the table @zerkms  I have updated

Comment: `RANGE` only works with rows counts, and unfortunately you cannot refer to any values from the row. So depending on your original task you might have used `INNER JOIN` + `GROUP BY` instead.

Comment: @zerkms so what would be the possible workaround ? thanks

Comment: Join the same table to itself, use join condition to select that timeframe and group by PK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>  RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED
> ```

Yep ... PostgreSQL's window functions don't yet implement ranges.

I've had many situations where they would've been useful, but it's a lot of work to implement them and time is limited.

> Is there any method to implement, say, a 10 second window for avg() window function?

You will need to use a left join over `generate_series` (and, if appropriate, aggregation) to turn the range into a regular sequence of rows, inserting null rows where there's no data, and combining multiple data from within one second to a single value where there are multiple values.

Then you do a `(ROWS n PRECEDING ...)` window over the left-joined and aggregated data to get the running average.