# Postgresql cumulative sum Last 3 days

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have this data and I want to compute a rolling 3-day  sum like below.

Note: Missing `date` has to be considered. So isn't just the last 3 rows, but 3 solar days.

[image]
[image]

I tried with a window function but it's not working:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(clicks) OVER (ORDER BY DATE ASC ROWS BETWEEN DATE - INTERVAL '3 day' AND date)
FROM table
```

Comment: I am using Postgres 11 (i added P9.1 tag by mistake). Anyway I tested with Postgresq on localhost but i get a syntax error near ")"

Comment: Your description says "missing date has to be considered. So isn't just the last 3 rows". But the picture of your data doesn't include any missing days. Please post sample data - as text not an image - covering your requirements.

Comment: With the " INTERVAL '3 day'" as suggested in the first answer I will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upper bound should be `current row` and `range`:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(clicks) OVER (ORDER BY DATE ASC range BETWEEN INTERVAL '3 day' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM table
```

Comment: When I try this i get the error:  SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED.    It seems like POstgres might not support this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791167/range-preceding-is-only-supported-with-unbounded

Comment: @cmrichards it is postgres syntax. Create a question and ping me again